Dockerfile returned error on msttcorefonts-installer after upgraded to dotnet core 8.0 from 6.0
I'm getting errors returned on this piece of code that worked fine with .NET 6.0:
RUN apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig && \
    update-ms-fonts && \
    fc-cache -f

After upgrading to .NET 8.0, I kept getting the error below.  Any help would be appreciated.

OpenSSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading. Unable to establish SSL connection. Connecting to ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net (ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net)|2801:82:80ff:13:ba59:9fff:fe86:2dd0|:443... failed: Network unreachable...

#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Chicago


RUN apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig && \
    update-ms-fonts && \
    fc-cache -f -v
  

ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=80
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
ENV LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
ENV LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./project", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:80"]


Does anyone know if the package is no longer available in Dotnet 8?  if so, what is replacement?  Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Does anyone know how to add msttcorefonts-installer for Dockerfile alpine in dotnet 8.0?  I googled but had no luck at this point.  So, Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Adding the scripts below caused error returned in compile and the issue is it couldn't download:
penSSL: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
1>#32 83.43 Unable to establish SSL connection.
https://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/corefonts/arialb32.exe
RUN apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig && 
update-ms-fonts && 
fc-cache -f
